# removeEventListener is not removing the event from the window

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have created two decorators, one that is attached to a method which creates a property on an object and attaches a function to the object to be added to an event listener later on.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-db5en9?file=index.ts)

It looks like this:

```js
export const EVENT_BINDING_PREFIX = '__attachEventBinding_'

export function Event(listenerLocation: string) {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    return Object.defineProperty(target, `${EVENT_BINDING_PREFIX}${propertyKey}`, {
      configurable: true,
      value: {
        type: 'event',
        name: listenerLocation.split(':'),
        binding: descriptor.value
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Next I have a binding that extends the object that it was attached to. When the object is instantiated, it adds the bindings that were created from the above function.

```js
export function GameObject(options?: object) {
  return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): object }>(constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
      constructor(...args: any[]) {
        super(...args)
        this.addBindings()
      }

      get bindings() {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)))
          .filter(i => i.startsWith(EVENT_BINDING_PREFIX))
          .map(b => (this as any)[b] as EventBinding)
      }

      addBindings() {
        this.bindings.forEach(binding => {
          const [nodeOrEvent, event] = binding.name
          if (nodeOrEvent === 'window' && event.length > 0) {
            window.addEventListener(event, binding.binding.bind(this))
          }
        })
      }

      removeBindings() {
        this.bindings.forEach(binding => {
          const [nodeOrEvent, event] = binding.name
          if (nodeOrEvent === 'window' && event) {
            window.removeEventListener(event, binding.binding.bind(this))
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I call `.removeBindings()`, the function runs `window.removeEventListener`. However, the binding actually never gets removed from the window. What is causing this to happen?

Here is how all of this is invoked:

```js
@GameObject({})
class Player {
  @AddEvent('window:click')
  windowClick() {
    console.log('here');
  }
}

const player = new Player();
setTimeout(() => {
  (player as any).removeBindings();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you `.bind` a function, you create a new one.

`removeEventListener` only works when the handler is the same (`===`) to the one passed to `addEventListener`.

```js
function foo() {}
const bound1 = foo.bind();
const bound2 = foo.bind();

// not the same
console.log(bound1 === bound2);
```

You'll need to save a reference to the bound function, something along the lines of

```
type AddedBindings = { eventName: string, fn: (...args: unknown[]) => unknown }[];
export function GameObject(options?: object) {
    return function <T extends { new(...args: any[]): object }>(constructor: T) {
      return class extends constructor {
        private addedBindings: AddedBindings = [];
```

```
addBindings() {
  const addedBindings: AddedBindings = [];
  this.bindings.forEach(binding => {
    const [nodeOrEvent, eventName] = binding.name
    if (nodeOrEvent === 'window' && eventName.length > 0) {
      const fn = binding.binding.bind(this);
      addedBindings.push({ eventName, fn });
      window.addEventListener(eventName, fn)
    }
  });
  this.addedBindings = addedBindings;
}

removeBindings() {
  this.addedBindings.forEach(({ eventName, fn }) => {
    window.removeEventListener(eventName, fn);
  });
}
```

Another option which might simplify the typings would be to persistently save a *function* that removes bindings, instead of saving the event names and handlers in a property.

```
addBindings() {
    const addedBindings = this.bindings
        .filter(({ name: [nodeOrEvent, eventName] }) => nodeOrEvent === 'window' && eventName.length > 0)
        .map((binding) => {
            const fn = binding.binding.bind(this);
            const eventName = binding[1];
            window.addEventListener(eventName, fn)
            return { eventName, fn };
        });
    this.removeAllBindings = () => {
        for (const { eventName, fn } of addedBindings) {
            window.removeEventListener(eventName, fn);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I was adding to an array at one point, but it was the wrong stuff, this fixes the issue thanks!!!